# Different behaviour on pressing back button and action bar back button?

Tags: android

When I go back to my previous activity

if I press the Action Bar back button then it updates UI, but when I press the back button then it doesn't makes the changes.

The function should be called is **updateUI** in **onCreateView**
It happens in the case of Action Bar back button but not the device's own back button.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_container);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), GRID_SIZE));

    updateUI();

    return v;
}
```

Here is the updateUI code :

```
private void updateUI(){
    List<Notes> mNotesList = NotesLab.getNotesList(getContext());
    Log.d(TAG, mNotesList.size()+"");
    if(mRecyclerAdapter == null){
        mRecyclerAdapter = new NotesRecyclerAdapter(mNotesList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
    } else{
        mRecyclerAdapter.setNotes(mNotesList);
        mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you overwritten onBackPressed?

Comment: The Action Bar "Back" is not actually back but called "Up" which provide two different types of navigation.
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

Just called the **updateUI** in **onResume( )**, silly me !